# Bootstrap datetimepicker won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to use the [Bootstrap datetimepicker:](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

I believe followed all the instructions, but I can't get it to work. `Firebug` does not give me any errors, and I checked all file paths many times. What am I doing wrong?

(I actually found the same question here, unanswered:
[Can't make datepicker bootstrap to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177032/cant-make-datepicker-bootstrap-to-work) )

Here's my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trj87ytj/)

And here's my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>date test</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class='col-sm-6'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
            </div>
        </div>    
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="moment.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="transition.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="collapse.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your fiddle jQuery library was not loaded .. Check this update : http://jsfiddle.net/trj87ytj/3/

Comment: I guess @SyedQarib is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trj87ytj/4/)

You had 2 issues:

1- **jQuery** library was missing
2- **jsfiddle's** div `Result` was overlapping the daterange picker button, so I added margin for testing :

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1' style="margin-top: 100px;">
```

Comment: Oh nice, that works! Could you explain to me what you mean by overlapping? So I just have to make sure I leave enough space? And how do I get it to work in my html file? It must still be the jquery problem there, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Oh I actually just figured it out! The jquery I mean - I still don't really understand the overlapping part, but it works!!

Comment: Overlapping means some div is appearing on top of your main element because that div has a higher z-index .. just make sure no div is appearing on top of daterange picker icon .. secondly, for jQuery issue, jQuery should be referenced first and all the libraries after that, also your reference link was broken, so make sure library is present there ..

Comment: @user3504783: now you are supposed to accept the answer to close this thread :)

Comment: Thank you! So how can I tell that a div is appearing on top of something? I mean, how do I know what z-index it has? Sorry, these are probably very stupid questions...

Comment: Google a bit .. usually these kinds of div's are placed as 'fixed' or 'static' positions .. like if you want the logo to be sticky on the header ..

Comment: That's very cool. You've taught me a lot! (I'll look into it!)

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
$(function () {
     $('.datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class='col-sm-6'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class='datetimepicker1 input-group date'>
                            <input  type='text' class="datetimepicker1 form-control" />
                            <span id='' class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Note** : *I removed `collapse.js` from external resource in jsfiddle , it was throwing some syntax error, and you were loading `jquery library 2.1` at last , I made the correction, assigned `id='datetimepicker1'` to `input` box instead of `div` *

[**View Working JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/trj87ytj/8/)

Comment: Thanks so much everybody! Unfortunately, none of those new fiddles here work on my computer! Is something wrong with my computer settings?? When I use the datetimepicker on the original website it works just fine. I'm including jquery.js in my code - is that not the right thing to do?

Comment: @user3504783 have you checked my jsfiddle , its working

Comment: I have, but it doesn't work for me:( When I click on the calender icon, nothing happens (my cursor also does not turn into a hand). Or do I have to do anything else?

Comment: @user3504783  click on input box :) , icon is just for styling, when you click on input box the DATEPICKER will be shown

Comment: Oh! Thanks! I can't believe I overlooked that! Is there any way I can get it to work by clicking on the calender icon? And how can I fix the jquery problem here on my computer (I already fixed the code with your suggestion)?

Comment: @CodingAnt: daterange picker is supposed to appear on icon click not on text field .. check the main example http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ .. and also check my answer ..

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle you did not reference the `jQuery` library.

It works in this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trj87ytj/1/)

Comment: It was not the problem of bootstrap library .. instead jQuery library was not loaded .. check the console ..

Comment: @SyedQarib: Yup.. My bad bro.. A simple comment could have been enough to correct my answer. Why the down vote bro ?

Comment: Can you tell me exactly why we have down votes ability on this platform ?

Comment: If the answer is irrelevant or completely useless.. And it can be undone if the answer is corrected.